# * not expanding in quotes

Tags: sh, quotes

I wrote a small shell script to package a Java project I'm working on into a jar file and copy it to my desktop and my flash drive, if plugged in. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME="ExeFinder.jar"
SRC_DIR="$HOME/Documents/Programs/Java/NetBeansProjects/ExeFinder/src"

javac $SRC_DIR/*.java # compile them in place
cp $SRC_DIR/*.class . # copy them here
rm $SRC_DIR/*.class # remove the ones there

mkdir src # make the dir for the source code
cp $SRC_DIR/*.java src # copy the source files to src

jar cfe $NAME ExeFinder ./*.class src # create the jar file

rm -r src # remove the temporary src; already in the jar
rm ./*.class # ditto for the class files

if [ -d /media/moses/Moses\ 8GB ]; then # if my flash drive is inserted
    cp ExeFinder.jar /media/moses/Moses\ 8GB # copy the jar file to it
fi

cp ExeFinder.jar ~/Desktop # copy it to my desktop
rm ExeFinder.jar # remove the old file
```

My problem is: When I run shellcheck on the file, it says "Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting", and highlights a few lines with `*` in them. When I surround these with double quotes, the `*` doesn't expand properly. Although it isn't necessary to surround these with quotes, I want to know if, and if so how, I can expand `*` in quotes.

Comment: You can't expand `*` inside quotes. That's one of the features of quotes - it prevents globbing, just as shellcheck suggested. But if you're worried that a directory stored in, say, `$SRC_DIR` might contain spaces or other special characters, you can quote *just that part*. For example, `cp "$SRC_DIR"/*.java src/`.

Comment: @ghoti Ok, thanks. You should post that as an answer so I can accept it!